# gdb print out a pointer is null or not

Tags: c, gdb

source:https://git.postgresql.org/cgit/postgresql.git/tree/src/backend/optimizer/plan/planner.c

```
(gdb) n
3556            if (root->group_pathkeys)
(gdb) s
3558            else if (root->window_pathkeys)
(gdb) print root->group_pathkeys==NULL
No symbol "NULL" in current context.
(gdb) s
3559                    root->query_pathkeys = root->window_pathkeys;
(gdb) s
query_planner (root=root@entry=0x55ffb53fdb70, qp_callback=qp_callback@entry=0x55ffb3299ee0 <standard_qp_callback>, qp_extra=qp_extra@entry=0x7ffc5db45260) at ../../Desktop/pg_sources/main/postgres/src/backend/optimizer/plan/planmain.c:219
219             fix_placeholder_input_needed_levels(root);
```

based on above I can guess `root->group_pathkeys == NULL` and `root->query_pathkeys != NULL`
is possible to evaluate a expression use print. something like `print (root->group_pathkeys==NULL)` then return 1.

Comment: `NULL` is (usually) just 0 cast to a `void` pointer, right? Have you tried with `0` in place of `NULL`?

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks. seems works.

Comment: You could give that as a proper answer to your question in the box below. That way, you can later "accept" the answer, marking the issue resolved.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print root->group_pathkeys
```

is normally enough to see if it is zero.

`NULL` is normally not known to the debugger because it is not declared but defined (may be `#define NULL 0` or with  cast to void as jian said.).
(This may be changed by size-expensive compilation flags.)

So you can replace `NULL` by `0`. (Moreover, the debugger does not care much about the types.)

The above holds if `==` is supposed to be just the normal `==`. Otherwise one one need a pretty funny things to write.